# ApplePay Web - sessionError {code:"unknown"}

Tags: java, payment, applepay, applepayjs, applepay-web

I am getting ApplePayCancelEvent with 'sessionError' right after successful apple pay session creation in my web app.

On the browser, it shows apple pay payment dialog with 'Payment Not Completed' message and the dialog got closed.

### Following are the safari console logs:

```
[Log] getApplePaySession() for: https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession
[Log] getApplePaySession().onload() status: 200
[Log] ApplePayCancelEvent {isTrusted: true, sessionError: {code: "unknown", info: {}}, type: "cancel", target: ApplePaySession, currentTarget: ApplePaySession, …}
```

any clue.. folks ??

Comment: The only clue I got is to remove the registered card and add it back

Comment: Do you have any updates on this issue? I'm facing the same thing.